# Сhoosing the right NN model (speed / performance)

Tags: python, machine-learning, neural-network

Im beginner and this is my first steps.

Im already learning about different Neural Network architecture and i have a question:

Which model i should choice for Rasberry PI / android?

Im already tried "ResNet" with 98x98 resolution of images and that model requires almost full power of my PC. Exactly:

Model takes 2 GB of video card memory, 1.4~2 GB of RAM.

This model is not suitable for the android / Rasberry (low power).

Which model i should choice for my task?

P.S I expect at least 5~10 FPS on Rasberry and 10~15 on Android.

Comment: Generaly there is almost no rule of thumb, it is also highly dependent on whatever you are trying to achieve.

Comment: @JosefKorbel,  im trying to achieve simple object detection in images

Comment: Welcome to SO; please do take some time to read [What topics can I ask about here?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic), and notice that questions asking us to *recommend or find a book, tool, software library, tutorial or other off-site resource* are off-topic for SO.

Comment: https://pjreddie.com/darknet/tiny-darknet/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Object Detection on Raspberry Pi with 5-10FPS is highly unrealistic.

You can have a look at YOLO or SSD, for example YOLO has also a smaller implementation which can run on RPI but you will be happy with 1FPS.

Answer (score 2):

TinyYOLO is a smaller version of the original YOLO network. You could try that one.